"java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed" in a @Scheduled Timer
I'm on Wildfly 30.0.1.Final.
I have a @Singleton bean with no @ConcurrencyManagement  annotation (i.e. container-managed). One of its methods is annotated with @Schedule(hour="*", minute="*", second="*/10", persistent=false) (yes, every 10s) and @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW).
Everytime the timer expires, the function invokes another piece of code which:

selects 55 items from a MySQL table
For each record:

Either creates a new document in a MongoDB collection or updates an existing one
Deletes the record



The select query is perfomed via jakarta.persistence.criteria objects and the delete query is performed via jakarta.persistence.EntityManager.remove(Object entity)
As you can guess from the combination between 10s and 55 items, we are aiming at a frequent and quick processing.
Everything works flawlessly in my local environment (Wildfly on my Windows machine, MySQL on a local Docker container, MongoDB on a host on my network).
As soon I move to the test environment (AWS machines, Wildfly in a Linux container, MySQL-compatible Aurora Serverless, Atlas-hosted MongoDB), only few executions of the timer work correctly. Most of them return the following exception as soon as the select query is attempted:
13:40:10,402 WARN  [org.visiontech.commons.commerce.impl.ComputationExportBatchlet] (TimerScheduler - 3) A problem occurred in the SQL executor : Error advancing (next) ResultSet position [Operation not a
llowed after ResultSet closed]: org.hibernate.sql.exec.ExecutionException: A problem occurred in the SQL executor : Error advancing (next) ResultSet position [Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed]
        at org.hibernate@6.2.13.Final//org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.makeExecutionException(JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.java:300)
        at org.hibernate@6.2.13.Final//org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.advanceNext(JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.java:257)
        at org.hibernate@6.2.13.Final//org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.processNext(JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.java:134)
        at org.hibernate@6.2.13.Final//org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.AbstractJdbcValues.next(AbstractJdbcValues.java:19)
        at org.hibernate@6.2.13.Final//org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.RowProcessingStateStandardImpl.next(RowProcessingStateStandardImpl.java:66)
        at org.hibernate@6.2.13.Final//org.hibernate.sql.results.spi.ListResultsConsumer.consume(ListResultsConsumer.java:184)
        at org.hibernate@6.2.13.Final//org.hibernate.sql.results.spi.ListResultsConsumer.consume(ListResultsConsumer.java:33)
        at org.hibernate@6.2.13.Final//org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.doExecuteQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:361)
        at org.hibernate@6.2.13.Final//org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.executeQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:168)
        at org.hibernate@6.2.13.Final//org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.list(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:93)
        at org.hibernate@6.2.13.Final//org.hibernate.sql.exec.spi.JdbcSelectExecutor.list(JdbcSelectExecutor.java:31)
        at org.hibernate@6.2.13.Final//org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.SingleIdLoadPlan.load(SingleIdLoadPlan.java:146)
        at org.hibernate@6.2.13.Final//org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.SingleIdLoadPlan.load(SingleIdLoadPlan.java:118)
        at org.hibernate@6.2.13.Final//org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.SingleIdEntityLoaderStandardImpl.load(SingleIdEntityLoaderStandardImpl.java:73)
        at org.hibernate@6.2.13.Final//org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.doLoad(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3521)
        at org.hibernate@6.2.13.Final//org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3511)
        at org.hibernate@6.2.13.Final//org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:581)
        at org.hibernate@6.2.13.Final//org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromCacheOrDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:567)
        at org.hibernate@6.2.13.Final//org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:536)
        at org.hibernate@6.2.13.Final//org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:529)
        at org.hibernate@6.2.13.Final//org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:202)
        at org.hibernate@6.2.13.Final//org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:241)
        at org.hibernate@6.2.13.Final//org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:106)
        at org.hibernate@6.2.13.Final//org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:78)
        at org.hibernate@6.2.13.Final//org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:138)
        at org.hibernate@6.2.13.Final//org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoadNoChecks(SessionImpl.java:1231)
        at org.hibernate@6.2.13.Final//org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1075)
        at org.hibernate@6.2.13.Final//org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.entity.internal.EntitySelectFetchInitializer.initializeInstance(EntitySelectFetchInitializer.java:197)
        at org.hibernate@6.2.13.Final//org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.InitializersList.initializeInstance(InitializersList.java:70)
        at org.hibernate@6.2.13.Final//org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.StandardRowReader.coordinateInitializers(StandardRowReader.java:111)
        at org.hibernate@6.2.13.Final//org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.StandardRowReader.readRow(StandardRowReader.java:87)
        at org.hibernate@6.2.13.Final//org.hibernate.sql.results.spi.ListResultsConsumer.consume(ListResultsConsumer.java:199)
        at org.hibernate@6.2.13.Final//org.hibernate.sql.results.spi.ListResultsConsumer.consume(ListResultsConsumer.java:33)
        at org.hibernate@6.2.13.Final//org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.doExecuteQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:361)
        at org.hibernate@6.2.13.Final//org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.executeQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:168)
        at org.hibernate@6.2.13.Final//org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.list(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:93)
        at org.hibernate@6.2.13.Final//org.hibernate.sql.exec.spi.JdbcSelectExecutor.list(JdbcSelectExecutor.java:31)
        at org.hibernate@6.2.13.Final//org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.lambda$new$0(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:110)
        at org.hibernate@6.2.13.Final//org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.withCacheableSqmInterpretation(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:303)
        at org.hibernate@6.2.13.Final//org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.performList(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:244)
        at org.hibernate@6.2.13.Final//org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.QuerySqmImpl.doList(QuerySqmImpl.java:518)
        at org.hibernate@6.2.13.Final//org.hibernate.query.spi.AbstractSelectionQuery.list(AbstractSelectionQuery.java:367)
        at org.hibernate@6.2.13.Final//org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:119)
        at deployment.o.ear//org.visiontech.commons.persistence.impl.store.AbstractIdentifiableEntityStore.performQuery(AbstractIdentifiableEntityStore.java:106)
        at deployment.o.ear//org.visiontech.commons.persistence.impl.store.AbstractIdentifiableEntityStore.find(AbstractIdentifiableEntityStore.java:95)
        at deployment.o.ear//org.visiontech.commons.persistence.impl.store.AbstractIdentifiableEntityStore.find(AbstractIdentifiableEntityStore.java:82)
        at deployment.o.ear//org.visiontech.commons.persistence.impl.store.AbstractIdentifiableEntityStore.find(AbstractIdentifiableEntityStore.java:78)
        at deployment.o.ear//org.visiontech.commons.commerce.impl.store.TokenConsumptionsQueueEntryStoreImpl$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.find(Unknown Source)
        at deployment.o.ear//org.visiontech.commons.commerce.impl.ComputationExportBatchlet.oneByOneProcess(ComputationExportBatchlet.java:66)
        at deployment.o.ear//org.visiontech.commons.batch.impl.AbstractOneByOneBatchlet.process(AbstractOneByOneBatchlet.java:17)
        at deployment.o.ear.w//TokenExporter.programmaticTimeout(TokenExporter.java:52)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.jboss.as.ee@30.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:35)
        at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:50)
        at org.jboss.as.ee@30.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:44)
        at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:509)
        at org.jboss.as.weld.common@30.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.delegateInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:62)
        at org.jboss.as.weld.common@30.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:72)
        at org.jboss.as.weld.common@30.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:87)
        at org.jboss.as.ee@30.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:44)
        at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:50)
        at org.jboss.as.ee@30.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:44)
        at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3@30.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:26)
        at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ee@30.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:28)
        at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:40)
        at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:53)
        at org.jboss.as.ee@30.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:35)
        at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3@30.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.singleton.SingletonComponentInstanceAssociationInterceptor.processInvocation(SingletonComponentInstanceAssociationInterceptor.java:36)
        at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3@30.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:39)
        at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3@30.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:237)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3@30.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.requiresNew(CMTTxInterceptor.java:399)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3@30.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:145)
        at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:509)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.2.Final//org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:87)
        at org.jboss.as.weld.common@30.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:72)
        at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3@30.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:24)
        at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3@30.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.IdentityOutflowInterceptor.processInvocation(IdentityOutflowInterceptor.java:56)
        at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3@30.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityDomainInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityDomainInterceptor.java:27)
        at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:509)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3@30.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.singleton.ContainerManagedConcurrencyInterceptor.processInvocation(ContainerManagedConcurrencyInterceptor.java:89)
        at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3@30.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:47)
        at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ee@30.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:33)
        at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:60)
        at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:438)
        at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@2.2.2.Final//org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:633)
        at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:57)
        at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:53)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3@30.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.TimedObjectInvokerImpl.invoke(TimedObjectInvokerImpl.java:85)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3@30.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.TimedObjectInvokerImpl.callTimeout(TimedObjectInvokerImpl.java:63)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3@30.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.distributable.DistributableTimer.invoke(DistributableTimer.java:96)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3@30.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.distributable.DistributableTimeoutListener.invoke(DistributableTimeoutListener.java:57)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3@30.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.distributable.DistributableTimeoutListener.timeout(DistributableTimeoutListener.java:48)
        at org.wildfly.clustering.ejb.infinispan@30.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.clustering.ejb.infinispan.timer.InfinispanTimer.invoke(InfinispanTimer.java:76)
        at org.wildfly.clustering.ejb.infinispan@30.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.clustering.ejb.infinispan.timer.TimerScheduler$InvokeTask$1.call(TimerScheduler.java:160)
        at org.wildfly.clustering.ejb.infinispan@30.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.clustering.ejb.infinispan.timer.TimerScheduler$InvokeTask$1.call(TimerScheduler.java:124)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at org.wildfly.clustering.context@30.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.clustering.context.ContextReferenceExecutor.execute(ContextReferenceExecutor.java:32)
        at org.wildfly.clustering.context@30.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.clustering.context.ContextualExecutor$1.run(ContextualExecutor.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:513)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Error advancing (next) ResultSet position [Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed] [n/a]
        at org.hibernate@6.2.13.Final//org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:61)
        at org.hibernate@6.2.13.Final//org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:108)
        at org.hibernate@6.2.13.Final//org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:94)
        ... 125 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed
        at com.mysql.mysql-connector-j@8.0.31//com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
        at com.mysql.mysql-connector-j@8.0.31//com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
        at com.mysql.mysql-connector-j@8.0.31//com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89)
        at com.mysql.mysql-connector-j@8.0.31//com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63)
        at com.mysql.mysql-connector-j@8.0.31//com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.checkClosed(ResultSetImpl.java:485)
        at com.mysql.mysql-connector-j@8.0.31//com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.next(ResultSetImpl.java:1802)
        at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@3.0.4.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedResultSet.next(WrappedResultSet.java:2689)
        at org.hibernate@6.2.13.Final//org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.advanceNext(JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.java:254)
        ... 123 more


I'm having a hard time figuring out what might be happening:

I'm not doing any manual Transaction/Session/ResultSet handling;
The timer expiration handler often fails also at its very first execution, so it's not a matter of subsequent handlers stepping onto each other.

I'm providing you with the code, for the sake of completeness:
The bean with the timer:
//imports

@Singleton
public class TokenExporter extends AbstractClusterSingleton implements ClusterSingleton {

    @Inject
    @ConfigProperty(name="computation.export.interval", defaultValue="10000")
    private Long interval;

    @Inject
    @ConfigProperty(name="computation.export.active", defaultValue="false")
    private Boolean active;
    
    @Inject
    private ComputationExportWorker computationExportWorker;
    
    @Inject
    private Logger logger;

    @Override
    protected void init(String key) {
        if (ObjectUtils.allNotNull(active) && active) {
            logger.info("TokenExporter active");
            if (logger.isInfoEnabled()) {
                logger.info("Scheduled first TokenExporter execution");
            }
        }
        else {
            logger.info("TokenExporter not active");
        }
    }

    @Schedule(hour="*", minute="*", second="*/10", persistent=false)
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void programmaticTimeout() {
        logger.info("TokenExporter scheduled execution start");
        if (ObjectUtils.allNotNull(active) && active) {
            try {
                computationExportWorker.process();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                logger.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
            } finally {
                logger.info("TokenExporter scheduled execution end");
            }
        } else {
            logger.info("TokenExporter not active");
            logger.info("TokenExporter scheduled execution end");
        }
    }

}

This is the ancestor of ComputationExportWorker, which ensures no multiple executions of the same code are performed:
package org.visiontech.commons.batch.impl;

//imports

public abstract class AbstractOneByOneWorker extends AbstractJobWorker {

    private static final AtomicInteger semaphore = new AtomicInteger();

    @Override
    public final String process() throws Exception {
        if (semaphore.getAndIncrement() > 0) {
            semaphore.getAndDecrement();
            return BatchStatus.ABANDONED.toString();
        } else {
            try {
                oneByOneProcess();
            } finally {
                semaphore.getAndDecrement();
            }
            return BatchStatus.COMPLETED.toString();
        }
    }
    
    public abstract void oneByOneProcess() throws Exception;
}

Finally, this is ComputationExportWorker, implementing the oneByOneProcess() method:
package org.visiontech.commons.commerce.impl;

// imports

public class ComputationExportWorker extends AbstractOneByOneWorker {

    @Inject
    @ConfigProperty(name="computation.export.readbatchsize", defaultValue="55")
    private Integer readBatchSize; 
    
    @Inject
    private JobQueueEntryStore jqeStore;
    
    @Inject
    private TokenConsumptionsQueueEntryStore tcsqeStore;

    @Inject
    private JobDocumentStore jobDocumentStore;
    
    @Inject
    private TokenConsumptionsDocumentStore tokenConsumptionsDocumentStore;
    
    @Inject
    private Logger logger;
    
    @Override
    public void oneByOneProcess() throws Exception {
        try {
            if (logger.isInfoEnabled())
                logger.info("ComputationExportWorker - Start processing");

            SimpleFindOrder<TokenConsumptionsQueueEntry, Date> tcsqeOrderByCreation = new SimpleFindOrder<>();
            tcsqeOrderByCreation.setField(CreatableEntity_.CREATION);
            FindResult<TokenConsumptionsQueueEntry> tcsqeResults = tcsqeStore.find(
                Arrays.asList(CriteriaUtils.getSimpleInstance(new TokenConsumptionsQueueEntry())),
                Arrays.asList(tcsqeOrderByCreation),
                readBatchSize, 0
            );

            SimpleFindOrder<JobQueueEntry, Date> jqeOrderByCreation = new SimpleFindOrder<>();
            jqeOrderByCreation.setField(CreatableEntity_.CREATION);
            FindResult<JobQueueEntry> jqeResults = jqeStore.find(
                Arrays.asList(CriteriaUtils.getSimpleInstance(new JobQueueEntry())),
                Arrays.asList(jqeOrderByCreation),
                readBatchSize, 0
            );

            if (tcsqeResults.getCount() > 0) {
                if (logger.isInfoEnabled())
                    logger.info("ComputationExportWorker - found " + tcsqeResults.getResults().size() + " TokenConsumptions queue entries. Min creation: " + tcsqeResults.getResults().stream().findFirst().get().getCreation() + ", max creation: " + tcsqeResults.getResults().stream().map(tcsqe -> tcsqe.getCreation()).reduce((first, second) -> second).orElse(null));

                tcsqeResults.getResults().stream().forEach(
                    ThrowingConsumer.transform(
                        tcsqe -> {
                            
                            //Operations on MongoDB
                            
                            tcsqeStore.delete(Arrays.asList(tcsqe));
                            logger.info("ComputationExportWorker - TokenConsumptionsQueueEntry deleted");
                        }
                    )
                );

            } else {
                if (logger.isInfoEnabled())
                    logger.info("ComputationExportWorker - No TokenConsumptions queue entries found");
                }

            if (jqeResults.getCount() > 0) {
                if (logger.isInfoEnabled())
                    logger.info("ComputationExportWorker - found " + jqeResults.getResults().size() + " Job queue entries. Min creation: " + jqeResults.getResults().stream().findFirst().get().getTokenConsumption().getCreation() + ", max creation: " + jqeResults.getResults().stream().reduce((first, second) -> second).orElse(null).getTokenConsumption().getCreation());
                jqeResults.getResults().stream().forEach(
                    ThrowingConsumer.transform(
                        jqe -> {
                            
                            //Operations on MongoDB
                            
                            jqeStore.delete(Arrays.asList(jqe));
                            logger.info("ComputationExportWorker - JobQueueEntry deleted");
                        }
                    )
                );

            } else {
                if (logger.isInfoEnabled()) {
                    logger.info("ComputationExportWorker - No Job queue entries found");
                }
            }
            if (logger.isInfoEnabled())
                logger.info("ComputationExportWorker - End processing");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.warn(ex.getMessage(), ex);
            logger.info("ComputationExportWorker - Erroneous processing");
        }
        
    }
    
}


